# How to make a hierarchical index from data in the columns?

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have tried and searched for two days on this (I'm still quite the noob). Can anyone help me with this probably simple task?

I am practicing with data in this format:

```
df = DataFrame({'year':[2010]*5 + [2011]*5, 'names':['a','b','c','d','e']*2, 'births':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})


    births names  year
0       1     a  2010
1       2     b  2010
2       3     c  2010
3       4     d  2010
4       5     e  2010
5       6     a  2011
6       7     b  2011
7       8     c  2011
8       9     d  2011
9      10     e  2011
```

And I want to get it in this format:

```
Year Name   births
2010   a    1
       b    2
       c    3
       d    4
       e    5
2011   a    6
       b    7
       c    8
       d    9
       e    10
```

I want it like this so I can easily access it with a combined primary key like `df.ix('2010','a')` --- I don't know if this is even possible or if it is how to reference it

Can anyone explain how I do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = df.set_index(['year', 'names'])` will give you what you want. You can access elements as

```
In[781]: df.set_index(['year', 'names']).xs(2010)
Out[777]: 
       births
names        
a           1
b           2
c           3
d           4
e           5
In[782]: df.set_index(['year', 'names']).xs([2010, 'a'])
Out[778]: 
births    1
Name: (2010, a), dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't passing it as a list